# Replace all characters except letters, numbers, spaces and underscores

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, ereg-replace

I am looking to replace all characters in a string except letters, numbers, spaces and underscores.

Could someone please provide a example?

Comment: What examples have you found that don't work? How do they not work?

Comment: I will also add that for string manipulation questions of all sorts, it helps to get the right answer if you provide a concrete example or two of what you would have going into the manipulation and what you would like to have coming out of the manipulation.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I normally use something like:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^ \w]+/", "", $string);
```

That replaces all non-space and non-word characters with nothing.

Comment: you should use single quotes for regex in PHP `preg_replace('/[^ \w]+/', '', $string)` double quotes with \ in them can result in unexpected behaviour

Comment: you should say all non-english characters, for example it removes Cyrillic symbols too

Answer (score 31):

```
[^0-9a-zA-Z_\s]
```

is what you want to replace.

Comment: This one helped me on a similar issue. Thanks! (For others reading this, don't forget to wrap it in slashes like this: `$new_string=preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z_]/',"",$old_string)` I took out the \s because I didn't need to allow spaces.

Comment: `\s` does not mean space always...

Answer (score 8):

```
<?php
$string = 'April 15, 2003';
$pattern = '/[^\w ]+/';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```